# Debian 10 Android Studio and Sdk installation problem

Tags: android-studio, debian

I'm following google's tutorial for installing android studio on Debian 10

I run command sh studio.sh from where this file is, of course. Then Android studio asks me android sdk location and I can't make it work

This is how my installations was done:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, it doesn't like this nested path:

```
/home/juliana/apps/Android/Sdk/android-studio/bin
```

Try to install Android Studio to:

```
/home/juliana/apps/Android/android-studio
```

And the Android SDK to:

```
/home/juliana/apps/Android/Sdk
```

---

For example: Here I use paths alike `/home/google/android-sdk` &  `/home/google/android-studio`, which are both owned by `me`, so that I have full R/W access for updating both. Since the updates are not run by `root`, the default 3rd party path `/opt` tends to be rather problematic.

---

Here's a script for cleaning up the mess ...

```
sudo mkdir /home/google
sudo chown -R juliana:juliana /home/google
mv ~/apps/Android/android-studio /home/google/android-studio
mv ~/apps/Android/Sdk /home/google/android-sdk
mkdir /home/google/android-avd
/home/google/android-sdk/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: yes, i had tried this before, it does not work. i did not install it on user/local as docs says because of permissions problems

Comment: @tramada Installing it directly into the user's home is also problematic, because when taking a backup of it, it will contain several gigabytes of irrelevant data... added a small script, where directory `android-avd` is intended for virtual devices.

Comment: Just noticed that you're missing the SDK... you'll have to delete that `.tar.gz` from there and then select `android-sdk` as SDK location, to be selected in Android Studio, where it can put the downloads... once it runs, it will certainly complain about the SDK location, but this need to be downloaded first.

Comment: I had not downloaded sdk... so stupid. thanks for folder structure tip

Comment: actually, by their docs video sdk should be there already. I tried downloading de sdk command line tools, but it's not that either